# What is the single less than in a ruby class

Tags: ruby

Example:

```
class YourName < Library::Method
  # code in here
end
```

I see it all the time in ruby and I have no idea what it means.

Comment: *less than*, you mean `<`, right?

Comment: It's syntax error and makes no sense. Did you mean `class YourName < Library::Method`?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant `<`

Comment: If you ask about such basic things as class inheritance, you should start from tutorials/courses/books instead of asking questions here.

Comment: @MarekLipka I've been going through [treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com) but I hadn't learned about class inheritance.

Comment: '<' means inherits from.... (your code)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the inheritance operator ([`<`](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Object_Oriented_Programming#Ruby_Class_Inheritance))

It means "YourName inherits from Library::Method"

Comment: The link to the doc is broken.  Here's [another one](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Object_Oriented_Programming#Ruby_Class_Inheritance).

Comment: thanks @Dominus.Vobiscum - you know you can actually `Edit` the answer - which will add to your reputation score

Comment: Honestly I didn't want to wait for it to get approved haha.  But thanks, I just submitted a suggestion 